# How to sort an array in-place given an array of target indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

How would you sort a given array `arr` **in-place** given an array of target indices `ind`?

For example:

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
var ind = [ 4,   0,   5,   2,   1,   3 ];

rearrange(arr, ind);

console.log(arr); // => ["B", "E", "D", "F", "A", "C"]

arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
ind = [ 2,   3,   1,   0 ];

rearrange(arr, ind);

console.log(arr); // => ["D", "C", "A", "B"]
```

I tried the following algorithm, but it fails on the second example above.

```
function swap(arr, i, k) {
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[k];
  arr[k] = temp;
}

function rearrange(arr, ind) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (ind[i] !== i) {
      swap(arr, i, ind[i]);
      swap(ind, i, ind[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

How would you solve this in O(n) time and O(1) extra space?

Could you provide a proof that your algorithm works?

---

**Note:** This question looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37460524/247243), but here mutating `ind` is allowed.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460524/how-to-rearrange-an-array-by-indices-array) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723626/how-to-rearrange-an-array-by-indices-array-proof)?

Comment: Don't you have anything else cooking in the kitchen..?

Comment: @trincot If you read carefully, you'll see that the requirements in the other questions you linked are slightly different. I added a note at the end of the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm fails because it has only one loop over the indices of your list.

What happens in your algorithm is this :

```
i=0 -> ["A", "B", "C", "D"] , [ 2,   3,   1,   0 ]
i=1 -> ["C", "B", "A", "D"] , [ 1,   3,   2,   0 ]
i=2 -> ["C", "D", "A", "B"] , [ 1,   0,   2,   3 ]
i=3 -> ["C", "D", "A", "B"] , [ 1,   0,   2,   3 ]
```

Note how by the first swap, `1` is in position `0` and you will not visit it again unless you swap it with `0`, which does not happen in this example.

What your algorithm misses is an internal loop that runs through sub-cycles of indexes. Try replacing the `if` by `while` in `rearrange`:

```
function rearrange(arr, ind) {
   for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
      while (ind[i] !== i) {
         swap(arr, i, ind[i]);
         swap(ind, i, ind[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

**Note on complexity**: although this is a double loop, complexity does not change because at each swap, one element is correctly placed, and each element is read at most twice (once through the cycling, once though the for loop).

**Note on proof**: I will not do a complete proof of this algorithm here, but I can give leads. If `ind` is a permutation, then all elements belong to closed permutative sub-cycles. The `while` loop ensures that you're iterating entire cycles, the `for` loop ensures that you're checking for every possible cycle.

Comment: Seems correct to me. You use the index array to mark an element / cycle as being processed and thus can skip those, reducing complexity from O(n^2) for immutable inputs to an optimal O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to swap until the same index is reached and then take the next outer index.

```js
function swap(arr, i, k) {
    var temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[k];
    arr[k] = temp;
}

function rearrange(arr, ind) {
    var i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
        while (ind[i] !== i) {
            swap(arr, i, ind[i]);
            swap(ind, i, ind[i]);
        }
    }
}

var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
var ind = [ 4,   0,   5,   2,   1,   3 ];

rearrange(arr, ind);
console.log(arr); // => ["B", "E", "D", "F", "A", "C"]

arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
ind = [ 2,   3,   1,   0 ];

rearrange(arr, ind);
console.log(arr); // => ["D", "C", "A", "B"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would you solve this in O(n) time?

By simply using a **temporary** array and iterating the arrays twice, you can reduce it to `O(n)`

```
function rearrange(arr, ind) 
{
  var temp = [], len = arr.length;
  //first re-arrange in a new array
  for(var counter = 0; counter < len; counter++)
  {
     temp[ind[counter]] = arr[counter];
  }  
  //copy the values as per new indices from temp
  for(var counter = 0; counter < len; counter++)
  {
     arr[counter] = temp[counter];
  }  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that extra space allowed is O(1).

Comment: @MishaMoroshko sorry, didn't get what is meant by `extra space`

Answer (score 0):

If you satisfied with doing that with less complexity method, then there is a one:

- Make a new array with length equal to `arr` length and with empty objects
- `splice` the new array by the index of `ind[i]`, remove 1 object , and replace it with `arr[i]`
- Equalize the old array(`arr`) with the new one

```js
window.onload = function () {
    
    'use strict'; 
 
 var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
 var ind = [ 4,   0,   3,   2,   1,   5 ];
 var temp = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     temp[i] = '';
 }

 for (var v = 0; v < arr.length; v++) {
     temp.splice(ind[v], 1, arr[v]);
 }
 
 arr = temp;
 console.log(arr);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you return your result in a new array

```
   function createArray(arr, ind) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            result.push(arr[ind[i]]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is in O(n) time

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
var ind = [4, 0, 5, 2, 1, 3];
console.log(createArray(arr,ind))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of discussion on a similar problem [In-place array reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365814/in-place-array-reordering)

The difference is that in original problem `ind[i]` is a required index for element `arr[i]`, while in the similar problem `i` is a required index for element `arr[ind[i]]`

Going back to the original algorithm, a working alternative may be

```
function swap(arr, i, k) {
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[k];
  arr[k] = temp;
}

function rearrange(arr, ind) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (ind[i] !== i) {
      swap(arr, i, ind[i]);
      swap(ind, i, ind[i]);
      if (ind[i] < i) {
        i = ind[i]-1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's still `O(1)` space, but it makes redundant checks and may be more complex than `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit faster to "rotate" the cycles rather than use swaps. C example:

```
    // reorder A in place according to sorted indices in I
    // tA is temp value for A
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i != I[i]){
            tA = A[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = I[k])){
                A[k] = A[j];
                I[k] = k;
                k = j;
            }
            A[k] = tA;
            I[k] = k;
        }
    }
```